# Fetch columns from database using zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am trying to call two tables to call them names and insert it in a new table.

This is model code.

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = array(
            $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll(),        
            $JournalisticDataBase = new Application_Model_JournalisticMapper(),
            $SponosorDataBase = new Application_Model_GuestbookMapper() );
    $entries   = array();
    foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
        $entry = new Application_Model_JournalisticSponsor();
        $entry->setJS_ID($row->JS_ID)
              ->setJ_fullname($row->J_fullname)
              ->setS_fullname($row->S_fullname)
              ->setJS_VisitDate($row->JS_VisitDate);

        $entries[] = $entry;
    }
    return $entries;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific: what is the desired outcome, what do you get now, are there any errors etc. etc.

Comment: i want to take name from table and other name from other table then fetch all results to show it in new table.
the error is:  Cannot redeclare Application_Model_JournalisticSponsorMapper::fetchAll()

Comment: please be more specific, as of now you question and your code makes very little sense.

Answer (score 1):

might i would just suggest to change your method name which define in model

```
public function fetchAll() to any other like `public function fetchData()`
```

or something which would be as per zend or coding standard

may be this could be happen to make same function name as zend DB class already consist.

Please let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: thank you, that wasn't the big deal,  i am trying to join tables in zend model then fetch them to show them in view.